# what's the defference betwwen Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: javascript, browser

I want it works,but it only works on Chrome, in firefox and IE, it alert nothing,this's my code:

```
    var name;
function say() {
    alert(name);
}
function execute(someFunction, value) {
    name = value;
    someFunction;
}
execute(say(), "Hello");
```

Comment: `execute(say, "Hello");`

Answer (score 3):

The code is clearly wrong:

```
execute(say(), "Hello");
```

This passes the *return value* of `say()` to `execute`. However, you want to pass the *function*, so use `execute(say, "Hello");` and in that function use `someFunction()` to execute it.

---

Even though it probably/hopefully doesn't matter anymore, the code *does* work in Firefox - it alerts `undefined` since `say()` is executed before `execute()` runs. The same thing happens in Chrome - however, it uses an empty alert box instead of showing the string `undefined` since apparently chrome (or at least its developer console) has a global variable ?name? defined by default which is an empty string.

Comment: o rly? Chrome alerts undefined for me

Comment: Ah, `name === ''` in the chrome developer console. That's why I got an empty string instead of `undefined`.